# mysql root permission to update information_schema error

Tags: mysql, permissions, root

when i try to update one table(GLOBAL_VARIABLES) from information_schema db,

i get an error :

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'information_schema'
```

Although I am root user with all privileges ,

how can i fix permission. ?

or how can i update this table ?

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the global variables using SET, and read them using SHOW.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-system-variables.html for more info

Answer (score 5):

The `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` database is a "pseudo database" containing server-generated views and as far as I know, contains only read-only data. If you need to alter a variable, you need to go the standard way, see Per's answer. From the [mySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-schema.html):

> INFORMATION_SCHEMA is the information database, the place that stores information about all the other databases that the MySQL server maintains. Inside INFORMATION_SCHEMA there are several read-only tables. They are actually views, not base tables, so there are no files associated with them.

More detailed info on GLOBAL_VARIABLES [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/variables-table.html).

Comment: how can i update this variable in the table GLOBAL_VARIABLES ?