# Rename tablenames to UPPERCASE

Tags: mysql

I've found several scripts, similar to this below, online that gives a preview how all table names gonna look like once I fire the script:

```
select concat('RENAME TABLE ', TABLE_NAME, ' TO ', UPPER(TABLE_NAME), ';') from information_schema.TABLES where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_db'
```

But what I need is an upgrade script that actually updates the the table names in the db, and not just let me preview the names.

I'm aware of these buddies:

```
lower_case_table_names = 1
lower_case_file_system = 1
```

but this in not an option due to the fact that I cannot make changes in the .ini file on my domain - so rather than have to rename each table online I prefer an simple script that renames (and saves) all table names at once... - and how would such update-script look like...?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Aren't most implementations case insensitive?

Comment: `update information_schema.TABLES
set TABLE_NAME = UPPER(TABLE_NAME)
where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_db'`
Whet happens with this?

Answer (score 18):

I had similar problems when my hosting company moved MySQL database from Windows to Linux, had to change all tables names to uppercase:

First run this in the `SQL` window of `phpmyadmin`

`select concat('rename table ', table_name, ' to ' , upper(table_name) , ';') from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'your_schema_name';`

this produces a script that will change all tables names to uppercase copy the script and paste it into the `SQL` window and run.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something you might want to consider:

```
   Usage Notes for the INFORMATION_SCHEMA Database
   Although you can select INFORMATION_SCHEMA as the default database with a 
   USE statement,
   you can only read the contents of tables, 
   not perform INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE operations on them.
```

Link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-schema.html

**Here is one more link explaning the update on information schema problem:**

[mysql root permission to update information_schema error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438351/mysql-root-permission-to-update-information-schema-error)

**And the Comment:**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3438369/362574

**How Is information schema table implemented in mysql :**

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3335/how-is-information-schema-implemented-in-mysql

**Comment :**

https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/3336/12967

Answer (score -2):

```
select concat('ALTER TABLE ', TABLE_NAME, ' RENAME TO ', UPPER(TABLE_NAME), ';')
from information_schema.TABLES
where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_db'
```