# MySQL: Get constraint name and drop it in one statement

Tags: mysql, sql, dynamic, ddl, bulk

I am getting constraint name from:

```
SELECT
  constraint_name
FROM
  information_schema.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE
  constraint_schema = 'db' AND table_name = 'table';
```

then dropping it from the table. It works when done manually on local machine. Right now it is messing with my Jenkins build's db migration scripts.

Is there a way to do it in one statement?

> > Update
> >     
> >     Following query gave me Access denied for user root@localhost

```
DELETE
FROM
  information_schema.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE
  constraint_schema = 'db' AND table_name = 'table';
```

Comment: you want to drop all constraints in one swoop ?

Comment: It does not really make sense to delete from `information_schema` tables

Comment: [information_schema tables are read-only.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3438369/541091). You have to construct DDL statements to drop constraints.

Comment: also can you provide the code that you use to drop constraints

Comment: @Bulat why is that necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### To auto-generate drop constraints to be run:

```
SELECT concat('ALTER TABLE ', TABLE_NAME, ' DROP FOREIGN KEY ', CONSTRAINT_NAME, ';') as theString
FROM information_schema.key_column_usage 
WHERE CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = 'so_gibberish' 
AND referenced_table_name IS NOT NULL;

+---------------------------------------------------+
| theString                                         |
+---------------------------------------------------+
| ALTER TABLE fc_junction DROP FOREIGN KEY fc_cat;  |
| ALTER TABLE fc_junction DROP FOREIGN KEY fc_food; |
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

It auto-generates the strings to run. Massage the ordering if necessary. And off you go. Note that in Workbench/sqlyog you won't have the table bar output of course.

Comment: It definitely shows all the constraints for that DB. But how can I drop a particular constraint from the list?

Comment: run it ! (not sure what you mean) ... let's say you want 7 of 100 to run. put them in a xxx.sql file, and run it as an input file to mysql command line (with credentials and dbname) as part of your DevOps/Jenkins CI script.

Comment: uh, and then, add those constraints back, right ?!  For whatever reason you are doing this, this is playing with fire potentially, but then that is the life of a DevOps kinda guy